# what's the point of voting people up if it's just reversed?

Tags: support, up-votes, serial-voting

I was following someone on SO and voted several of his answers up. I found them helpful.

I checked today and found that all my votes for that particular person were reversed. Is there some hidden "limit" to the number of upvotes for a particular person / day? 4? 5? 6?

Comment: How many did you place?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can upvote whoever you want however many times you want (assuming you have not used up all of your daily votes). The system is able to check though and see if there are patterns to voting which would point out instances where someone gets downvoted repeatedly all at once or has multiple things upvoted all at once and will take steps to correct it.

If you mean by "reversed" that your votes just disappeared (allowing you to vote again on the topic), that is likely what had happened.

If what you mean by "reversed" is that you voted something up to "+1" and it's now at "0" or "-1", then that could be potentially explained simply by other users voting in the opposite direction.

Comment: thanks to everyone for their answers. I did vote elsewhere as well, so hopefully angry penguins won't undo my vote here.

Answer (score 14):

The key is that you shouldn't be voting *people* up to begin with. You should be voting *answers* (or questions) up.

The idea is to promote good posts, not good people. If people happen to write lots of good posts, then great - but judge based on the posts, not the name.

For example, when you voted several of this person's answers up, did you look at the other answers in the same questions, and vote up any other good ones? If so, that's fair - but if the *only* candidates for your upvotes are for one person, I think it's reasonable to object to that behaviour. (Aside from anything else, it promotes positive feedback on rep even more than the normal situation...0

Comment: Probably why question and answer voting is not allowed from a user's page.

Comment: I think that this doesn't catch the 'wikipedia' like aspect of SO. I recall many moons ago when a younger (32k) Jon Skeet answer my question and I was thoroughly impressed. I went through his profile, and found that there were other questions (that interested me) that he had answered with similar skill. So I voted them up too. It wasn't that I didn't evaluate each post based on it's own merits, it is that I discovered a user who had a strong tendency towards great answers. I'm not sure what happened to him, I haven't really kept up.

Comment: @devinb: As I say, I think that behaviour's not too so bad as long as you *also* checked the other answers for the same questions, to give other answers a fair chance of grabbing your votes.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's the way it should work, but unfortunately, that's not what happens. I've seen people targeted and their perfectly good questions downvoted out of pure spite.

Comment: @Ben: I dare say it happens, but not a huge amount... And if the serial voting script notices, it'll be reversed anyway.

Answer (score 11):

Your votes today were probably determined to be anomalous, see the blog [post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) on voting anomalies

Answer (score 2):

You may have been flagged for [vote fraud](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/more-voting-anomalies/) and all of your votes were annihilated (most likely by an angry penguin).

There is no limit to the upvotes a question or answer can receive.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with up- (or indeed down-) voting several answers from one person sequentially over a short period of time, however, it's one of the "vote fraud "behaviours that is checked for.

If you really want to up-vote all this persons answers do it over a longer period and vote on other questions/answers inbetween these votes.

Comment: On a related note, I invite you to attempt to hone your vote-fu on my answers, because, hey, I'm here for science.

Comment: I'm not sure I could ;)